# How to format the tooltip content in nvd3-angularjs

Tags: tooltip, stacked-area-chart, angularjs-nvd3-directives

Im using Stacked area chart of nvd3-angularjs

This is my html

```
<div ng-controller="Eth2GraphController">

    <nvd3-stacked-area-chart
    data="GraphData"
    noData="No Data For You!"
    id="eth2Graphs"
    showXAxis="true"
    showYAxis="true"
    showLegend="true"
    interactive="true"
    tooltips="true"
    objectEquality="true"
    margin="{left:100,right:100}"
    useInteractiveGuideline="true"
    tooltipcontent="toolTipContentFunction()"
    xAxisTickFormat="xAxisTickFormatFunction()"
    yAxisTickFormat="yAxisTickFormatFunction()"
    color="colorFunction()"
    legendColor="colorFunction()"
    >
        <svg></svg>
    </nvd3-stacked-area-chart>
</div>
```

Now, I have a function that should format the tooltipcontent, but its not working. Maybe it has something to do with the useInteractiveGuideline attribute. I used the same tooltipcontent function to edit the tooltip of my other charts, its working on those charts the only difference is that those chart dont use useInteractiveGuideline.

```
$scope.toolTipContentFunction = function() {
    return function(key, x, y, e, graph) {

        return        '<h3>' + x + '</h3>' + 
                 '<p>' + key + ' ' + y + '</p>';

    }
};
```

I want x to be in the center, and other formatting for the data. How would I do that? Am I using the correct attribute that would format the tooltip?

Answer (score 0):

1. Change `tooltipcontent="toolTipContentFunction()"` to:
   `tooltipContent="toolTipContentFunction"`
2. `useInteractiveGuideline` must be set to false for the `tooltipContent` to work. I believe it is because `useInteractiveGuideline` uses it's own popup.